# Element Ref variables not getting when passed by component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component in which i am passing a component by reference. I am able to get component but the properties inside passed component getting undefined

**app.component.html**

```
<app-home [cmpRef]="cmp"></app-home>
<app-container #cmp></app-container>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent {
  @Input() cmpRef: any

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.cmpRef) 

  }
}
```

**ContainerComponent.ts**

```
export class ContainerComponent {

  @ViewChild('one',{static:false}) one : any;
  @ViewChild('two',{static:false}) two : any;

}
```

**container.component.html**

```
<div #one>
  This is div One
</div>

<div #two>
  This is div Two
</div>
```

Demo Link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qhybe9?embed=1&file=src/app/container/container.component.ts

`console.log.(this.cmpRef)` gives below result

```
ContainerComponent {}one: ElementRef {nativeElement: div}two: ElementRef {nativeElement: div}__proto__: Object
```

But when i try to access `this.cmpRef.one` i am getting `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngAfterViewInit()` for this.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.cmpRef)
}
```

When you call `console.log(this.cmpRef)` in the `ngOnChanges` hook `ContainerComponent` view does not exist yet.